# Why does Pygame text print doesn't fully cover the last text print, and leaves weird aura around the text?

Tags: python, text, printing, pygame

I have 2 functions that are part from a program I have where I print a number of balls that is constantly changing, so I print it, but every time before I print it (calling set_text() and then printing), I call the set_text2() function so that the previous text will disappear,
however that doesn't work and it leaves a weird aura around the number.

These are the 2 functions in Python:

```
def set_text(string, coord_x, coord_y, font_size):
    """
    This is a function to set the text of the amount of balls (white)
    :param string: The text to display (in this case the amount of current balls)
    :type string: string
    :param coord_x: The x coordinate of the text
    :type coord_x: int
    :param coord_y: The y coordinate of the text
    :type coord_y: int
    :param font_size: The size of the text
    :type font_size: int
    :return: The text
    :rtype: tuple
    """

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', font_size)
    # (255, 255, 255) is black, to make black text
    text = font.render(string, True, (255, 255, 255))
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (coord_x, coord_y)
    return text, text_rect


def set_text2(string, coord_x, coord_y, font_size):
    """
    This is a function to set the text of the amount of balls (black)
    :param string: The text to display (in this case the amount of current balls)
    :type string: string
    :param coord_x: The x coordinate of the text
    :type coord_x: int
    :param coord_y: The y coordinate of the text
    :type coord_y: int
    :param font_size: The size of the text
    :type font_size: int
    :return: The text
    :rtype: tuple
    """

    # font_size+2 - trying to make the black text cover the white text
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', font_size)
    # (0, 0, 0) is black, to make black text
    text = font.render(string, True, (0, 0, 0))
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (coord_x, coord_y)
    return text, text_rect
```

How do I fix it?

Also, this is where I actually print the text:

```
    # Printing to the screen the current amount of balls on the screen
    print_amount = current_amount
    totalText = set_text(str(print_amount), 350, 20, 35)
    screen.blit(totalText[0], totalText[1])

    # If the amount of balls has changed, covering the previous amount (Black text)
    if print_amount != current_amount:
        totalText = set_text2(str(print_amount), 350, 20, 35)
        screen.blit(totalText[0], totalText[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using antialising. This means that some pixels are not actually the color you originally selected, but essentially a smoothing pass was made that also bleeds into surrounding pixels.<sup>1</sup> You can check this for yourself by passing `False` as the second parameter to `font.render` instead of `True`. Then the effect should be gone.

However, it is probably better to use antialiasing, and instead change the method by which you are overdrawing the previous image:

- I assume you specially don't want to redraw the entire screen. You might want to reconsider that, since it will completely remove the possibility of these artifacts.
- Use the `background` parameter of `font.render`. This will not only overdraw the numbers, but also what is around them, so that might not be an option.

<sup>1 <strike>I am not entirely sure why the antialising is not applied to the black pixels in the same way. I assume this is caused by the transparent background also having color value `(0, 0, 0)`</strike> See below</sup>

---

After a bit more fiddling and investigation, I figured it out: AA pixels have an alpha value set, to allow for blending with the background. However, applying an alpha for black and for white have different results: While blending with white makes the pixel visible for sure, blending with black does not make fully black. I don't think there is really a way around this unless someone knows a way to make any non zero alpha behave like 255 Alpha.

Comment: Changing the second parameter from False to True did the job, thank you!